# I have null values when adding data to a table in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have the insertion into two tables with this code, the problem is that it only adds to one. Only the insert works in "tbl_comprobaantes_usr_curso", but in tbl_resultados i have "null" in console.
This is the complete code:

```
internal static bool RegistrarResultados(ResultadosModel resultadosModel)
        {
            bool is_ok = false;

            // Crear objeto para tbl_comprobantes_usr_curso
            tbl_comprobantes_usr_curso tbl_Comprobante = new tbl_comprobantes_usr_curso()
            {
                id_usuario = resultadosModel.UsuarioId,
                id_curso = 1,
                folio = " ",
                fecha_creacion = resultadosModel.FechaCreacion,
                path = " ",
                estatus = null,
                calificacion = resultadosModel.Aciertos * 10,
                d_fecha_descarga = DateTime.MinValue
            };

            // Crear objeto para tbl_resultados
            tbl_resultados tbl_Resultado = new tbl_resultados()
            {
                id_usuario = resultadosModel.UsuarioId,
                id_cuestionario = resultadosModel.CuestionarioId,
                fecha_creacion = resultadosModel.FechaCreacion,
                aciertos = resultadosModel.Aciertos,
                estatus = resultadosModel.Estatus
            };

            

            try
            {
                using (Entities db = new Entities())
                {
                    // Insertar en tbl_resultados
                    db.tbl_resultados.Add(tbl_Resultado);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    // Insertar en tbl_comprobantes_usr_curso
                    db.tbl_comprobantes_usr_curso.Add(tbl_Comprobante);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    is_ok = true;

                    // Log de información para tbl_resultados
                    Log.InfoLog(
                        LOG,
                        MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                        string.Format("Resultados de la evaluación guardados: usr {0} | cuestionario {1} | fecha {2}",
                            tbl_Resultado.id_usuario, tbl_Resultado.id_cuestionario, tbl_Resultado.fecha_creacion)
                    );

                    // Log de información para tbl_comprobantes_usr_curso
                    Log.InfoLog(
                        LOG,
                        MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                        string.Format("Comprobante de evaluación guardado: usr {0} | curso {1} | fecha {2}",
                            tbl_Comprobante.id_usuario, tbl_Comprobante.id_curso, tbl_Comprobante.fecha_creacion)
                    );
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log de error general
                Log.FatalLog(
                    LOG,
                    MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
                    string.Format("Error al salvar la evaluación Usr {0} | Cuestionario {1} | fecha {2} | Aciertos {3} | Estatus {4}",
                        resultadosModel.UsuarioId, resultadosModel.CuestionarioId, resultadosModel.FechaCreacion, resultadosModel.Aciertos, resultadosModel.Estatus),
                    ex
                );
            }

            return is_ok;
        }
```

I'm checking the value of tbl_Comprobante and tbl_Resultado, but i have in tbl_Resultado "null"

Comment: *but in tbl_resultados i have "null" in console.* This is unclear. Are you talking about log output? What exactly are you saying is "null" ?

Comment: same concern as topsail... do you have null in the console (command line)? Does the inserted record in tbl_resultados have null values when you query it? If you are referring to the values printed in the console by your Log.InfoLog(), which value are you getting null?